# Powershell create access policy Azure

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to create an access policy so that I can create meetings using Microsoft Graph API on the user's behalf. To do this I need to do a script that is similar to this:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
New-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity Random -AppIds "applicationid" -Description "Users"
Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName Random -Identity "userId"
```

But when I try to run the second line I get this error:

```
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MicrosoftTeams\2.3.1\net472\SfBORemotePowershellModule.psm1:63 char:22
+     $remoteSession = & (Get-CsOnlineSessionCommand)
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-CsOnlineSession], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Teams.ConfigApi.Cmdlets.GetCsOnlineSession
 
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is
 not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MicrosoftTeams\2.3.1\net472\SfBORemotePowershellModule.psm1:22959 char:38
+ ...    -Session (Get-PSImplicitRemotingSession -CommandName 'New-CsApplic ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the first command that it's not remembering my login, but I can't find anywhere on how to do this. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and what the correct way is?.

Edit:
I finished the first problem. I needed to create an account on the active directory itself because Microsoft accounts weren't allowed. But my second error is still here:

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is
 not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MicrosoftTeams\2.3.1\net472\SfBORemotePowershellModule.psm1:22959 char:38
+ ...    -Session (Get-PSImplicitRemotingSession -CommandName 'New-CsApplic ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Is there a way to set the session via a parameter or is this something you need to do outside this method?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this issue, would you clarify how you created an account on Azure AD to solve the first issue?

Comment: @Diana I already fixed the first problem, but it seemed like the edit was not that noticeable. I fixed it by creating an account on the active directory itself, so you were right with that my account creation was wrong but the second error still exists.